# Having an issue appending to list inside function

Tags: python, list, function, append

I have the following table that has a unique ID, actual, and modeled output.

```
   Pass_ID Actual Modeled 
0    100     1      1
1    101     0      1 
2    102     1      0  
3    103     1      1
```

I wrote the following function so I can generate a list which eventually I'll turn into a dataframe so I can easily call back the rows for each Pass_ID to see if I can isolate why the model is not working for those rows. However, the list keeps coming back empty.

```
new_list = []

def isolate_diff(df):
    if df['Modeled'].any() != df['Actual'].any():
        new_list.appened(df['Pass_ID'])
    else:
        pass

    return new_list
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Your code is incorrect. It should be `append` instead of `appened` in line 5.

Comment: You never call your `isolate_diff(df)` function. Try adding `new_list = isolate_diff(df)` to the bottom of your script

Comment: It is better to define `new_list` in `isolate_diff` because the function will return `new_list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Prune, but to solve it, i think you need a whole different solution:

```
print(df[df['Modeled']!=df['Actual']])
```

Output:

```
   Pass_ID  Actual  Modeled
1      101       0        1
2      102       1        0
```

If you want a list of `Pass_ID`:

```
print(df.loc[df['Modeled']!=df['Actual'],'Pass_ID'].tolist())
```

Output:

```
[101, 102]
```

Comment: wow. that's awesome. thanks so much. I think I over though it. really appreciate everyone's help

Answer (score 0):

You wrote a global condition, not a vectorized condition:

```
if df['Modeled'].any() != df['Actual'].any():
```

Each term is `True` if *any* element is `1`.  This evaluates quickly to

```
if True != True
```

which gets you an empty `new_list`.

Instead, write an expression grabbing `df['Pass_ID']`, *filtered* where `df['Modeled'] != df['Actual']`.  Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 0):

Change `new_list.appened(df['Pass_ID'])` to `new_list.append(df['Pass_ID'])`

Edit: Prune and U9 detected a few other errors. This was the first incorrect thing I saw. Please defer to their answers for more detailed revisions